# Do not check session on specific page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using sessions to check if the user is logged in. In my project, there are some pages, where session check is not required i.e user can access it without logging in. How I disable session check on selective pages? Instead of writing say session_check on every page that needs session, i want to know if there is a way to implement no_session_check() on selected pages. As the number of pages that require session check are more than pages that do not work. I am using codeigniter. Thanks

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

First you created the  session checking function  in library file .. if u want session on that controller just call that library function..

[Refer this link:](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)